# How to stop runAction in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

How to stop all actions in game after some time?

in below code i am calling runaction on a sprite.

```
id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration*2.5 position:ccp(winSize.width + (target.contentSize.width/2), actualY)];
id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)];
id sequece = [CCSequence actions:delayTime1, calFun1, delayTime2, calFun2,actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil];
id repeate = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:sequece];

[target runAction:repeate];
```

In this code a sprite is continuously moving. how to stop the above action after some time or after some condition ?

Answer (score 2):

In `runAction call Function` and `stop action` for `sprite`.

```
[CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setInvisible:)];

- (void)setInvisiblestone:(CCNode *)node
{
    [target stopAllActions];
}
```

Comment: runaction is call periodacllay after every 1 sec.. and even target is not a single object. its more thans once.  
runaction is called from
-(void)addTraget:(ccTime)dt{  } and addTraget is called as   [self schedule:@selector(addTraget:) interval:1.5]; so how to stop this action? which is scheduled

Comment: you may use this-code...[self unschedule:@selector(addTraget:)] or [self schedule:@selector(addTraget:) interval:1.5 repeat:NO delay:NO];

Answer (score -1):

All action stop in method.

```
-(void)gameover
{
     [self unscheduleAllSelectors];
}
```

Comment: Please use 4 spaces in front of the code to format it as code.

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question.